# Let $a_1 , a_2 > 0$ and for $j \ge 3$ define $a_j = a_{j-1} + a_{j-2}$. Show that this sequence cannot converge to a finite limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I was trying this problem and I wonder if I could have some feedback for my solution.

> Let $a_1 , a_2 > 0$ and for $j \ge 3$ define $a_j = a_{j-1} + a_{j-2}$. Show that this sequence cannot converge to a finite limit.

Suppose $\{a_j\}$ converges to finite number $L$.
Then, let $\epsilon = a_1 > 0$, and there exists $N$ such that $|a_j-a_{j+1}| < \epsilon = a_1$ for all $n > N$.
$$|a_j-a_{j+1}| = |a_j+a_{j-1}-a_j| = |a_{j-1}|$$
However, since $|a_{j-1}| > \epsilon = a_1$ for all $n$, it contradicts, and the sequence diverges.

Is this right? or is there anybody who can give some hints?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello. welcome to MSE. do you mean $$a_j=a_{j-1}+a_{j-2}$$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Why is $|a_{j-1}| > \epsilon = a_1$?

Comment: I observed that a_{n} > 0 by induction, so a_{n}= a_{n+2} -  a_{n+1}  is increasing sequence, and hence, I thought that a_{n-1} > a_{1}

Comment: Can you prove $a_n>nb$ for a suitable positive $b$?

Comment: My point is $a_{n-1} > a_1$ may be false for some $n$.  It's true for $n\geq 4$, which is all you need, but claiming it's true for all $n$ (as you do in the question) makes me think you haven't fully investigated it.  (If you fix that, I think your proof is fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both places where you’ve written $n$, you meant $j$. Also, we can only guarantee that $a_j>a_1$ for $j\ge 3$, since $a_2$ could be less than or equal to $a_1$. Those are small technical errors, and apart from them the argument is correct, except that you really ought to include justification for the fact that $a_j>a_1$ for $j\ge 3$, even though it’s a very easy proof by induction.

You might be interested in an alternative approach. Let $a=\min\{a_1,a_2\}$; clearly $a_2\ge a$ and $a_3\ge 2a$. Suppose that $n>3$, and $a_j\ge(j-1)a$ for $2\le j<n$. Then

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}\ge(n-2)a+(n-3)a\ge(n-1)a\,,$$

and by induction $a_n>(n-1)a$ for all $n\ge 2$. The sequence is therefore unbounded and cannot converge to a finite limit.

If you’re familiar with the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), you can use this same approach to show that $a_n\ge F_na$ for $n\ge 1$. It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding) that $F_n$ is the integer closest to $\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}$, where $\varphi=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)\approx 1.618>1$, so in fact the sequence $\langle a_n:n\ge 1\rangle$ grows exponentially fast.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That's really great answer.

Comment: @LOlolikelit: You’re very welcome; thank *you*!

Answer (score 0):

Another Idea : let $$\min \{ a_1 , a_2\}=m$$ and we know $m>0 $ so
$$a_3=a_2+a_1\geq m+m=2m$$
and
$$a_4=a_3+a_2\geq2m+m=3m\\a_5=a_4+a_3 \geq 3m+2m >4m\\\vdots\\a_n\geq(n-1)m ,m >0 \\\to \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n\to +\infty$$